# Injecting C# code from editor into runtime application and evaluation using Rosalyn scripting API

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, compiler-construction, algorithmic-trading

I am working on a feature for our automated trading system so that users can connect to our running system (when in simulation / testing mode) and code models / signals  and strategies on the fly. At the moment I am still toying with this and looking for ways to do this using Microsoft Rosalyn scripting API. Users write code in an embedded editor and inject it into the trading system which compiles and executes it on the fly.

Is there anyway I can link Visual Studio so that users can write / verify C# code in its editor and then click a button to remotely transfer the code to our trading system for execution on the fly using Rosalyn scripting API?

Answer (score 0):

Found it at https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit. It is something I can definitely use for this.